# Mac Outlook Calendar not using system calendar type of ISO 8601 for fiscal weeks

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

Disclosure: I already asked this [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/mac-outlook-calendar-not-using-system-calendar/c58648fd-7714-44da-8e31-61907a74e06e) but no one has responded and my super hero alter ego is "No Patience Man".

Hello,

I have done this on a different version of Mac, I think it was Big Sur, but on Monterey it seems to not be working.

System
OSx: v12.2.1
Outlook: v16.57 (22011101) - Using "New Outlook"

I have my `System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Calendar` on my Mac set to `ISO 8601`
[System Preferences -> Language & Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW5Cv.png)

Before, in outlook, I could also select to use the ISO calendar. Although from my reading, I found that it shouldn't make a difference. In the version of Outlook I'm using, I cannot.
[Outlook preferences -> Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJluP.png)

The ISO fiscal week for this week (15-Feb-2022) is 7, but Outlook is showing it as 8
[Last week FW in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH19J.png)[Last week FW epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ELC.png)

Update for this week
[This week FW in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfDtb.png)[This week FW epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQidw.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my search, the ISO week-numbering year starts at the first day (**Monday**) of week 01 and ends at the Sunday before the new ISO year (hence without overlap or gap).

So you need to change the First day to Monday in your Outlook.

[image]

Now the week number in Outlook and the ISO fiscal are showing the same

[image]
[image]

Hope this can help you!
If you think my answer is helpful, please accept the answer to help others:)

Comment: you're my hero.

Comment: Interestingly, the Sunday/Monday thing contradicts the comment below this answer to a similar question: https://superuser.com/a/1624888/55687